# typescript arrow function overload which take variable number of arguments

Tags: typescript, overloading

I am learning ts function overload with official ts handbook. There are some examples but only with `function` keyword. So, I'm trying to write with arrow function especially with various argument number. Here are some of my tries.

```js
interface DateGeneratorType {
    (timestamp: number): Date;
    (y: number, m: number, d: number): Date;
}

const dateFactory: DateGeneratorType = (yOrTs, m?, d?) =>
   ((m ?? false) && (d ?? false)) ? new Date(yOrTs, m, d) : new Date(yOrTs);
```

The first try bumped into `unknwon` type error. So, I have to specify the `unknown` type to `number` type.

```js
const dateFactory: DateGeneratorType = (yOrTs, m?, d?) =>
{
    if ((m ?? false) || (d ?? false)) {
        if (typeof m === 'number' && typeof d === 'number')
            return new Date(yOrTs, m, d);
        throw Error('invalid');
    } else {
        return new Date(yOrTs);
    }
}
```

It works but isn't satisfying. Is there other ways to do this without using `any`?

Comment: Those `m ?? false` conditions are quite unconventional, I don't think TS can infer the type from them. It works with a `typeof m === "number" && typeof d === "number"` condition.

Comment: all examples are with the function syntax since that syntax has built-in support for overloads. why would you want to use the arrow function in your case? it doesn't have anything specific that related to `this`, so the usage should be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define types in impl arguments, and to remove confusing `&& false`

```
const dateFactory: DateGeneratorType = (yOrTs: number, m?: number, d?: number) =>
   m && d ? new Date(yOrTs, m, d) : new Date(yOrTs);
```